# Marionette - constructor vs initialize

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I noticed that Marionette views define a `constructor` method, instead of `initialize`. What's the purpose of it - why not just use Backbone's `initialize`, which is still being called during instantiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common to implement `initialize` in your own `View` types.

If Marionette Views used `initialize`, you would need to remember to call the parent method to get the default behaviour. Most of your Views would look like this:

```
var MyView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    Marionette.ItemView.prototype.initialize.call(this);
    this.x = options.x;
  }
});
```

This isn't necessary because Marionette uses `constructor` rather than `initialize`.